# Python for FTP-only webhosting

Tags: python, deployment, web-hosting, packaging

I would like to develop a Python web app and deploy that to some shared web hosting. Point is, only access is via FTP, so ssh-ing into it and running `pipenv` or `virtualenv` is no option.

To complicate things more, they run an older version of Python than I have at my command (3.5 vs 3.8)

How could I create and package a Python application including dependencies?

Bonus question: runtime model is just CGI, so the environment needs to be activated from within the CGI-script.

Comment: Best bet is to use better hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Starting with the bonus question:

[`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer) allows to install (almost) arbitrary python versions alongside the current environment.
Install `pyenv` by

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer/raw/master/bin/pyenv-installer | bash
```

Activate with

```
export PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

[Install Python 3.5.3](https://gist.github.com/jaydenkieran/75b2bbc32b5b70c4fdfb161ecdb6daa2)

```
$ pyenv install 3.5.3
Downloading Python-3.5.3.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.3/Python-3.5.3.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.3...
Installed Python-3.5.3 to /home/snakebite/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3
```

and activate

```
export PYENV_VERSION=3.5.3
```

#### Packaging for CGI deployment

I didn't know much about python packaging before, it always felt confusing. There might be reasons for that.... Good reads are

- [A Curriculum for Python Packaging](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2018/10/22/a-curriculum-for-python-packaging/)
- [12 Trending Alternatives for Distributing Python Applications in 2020](https://tryexceptpass.org/article/distributing-python-applications/)
- [PEX](https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex)
- [SHIV](https://shiv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

PEX is a way to package and distribute python scripts with all their dependencies as a ZIP file in a kind of virtual environment that is executable by the python interpreter. Very much recommended introduction video by Twitter University: [WTF is PEX?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmpnGhRwsu0)

The application is run from the ZIP directly, only unpacking libraries that are marked unsafe for running off the ZIP into a caching directory (defaulting to `~/.pex`), keeping the performance impact at bay. `shiv` claims to be even faster.